# DateComponents() Swift ветка if

Tags: ios, swift, дата, datepicker

При разработке приложения столкнулся с проблемой .Проблема в том что никак не могу найти подход к компонентам из даты. Нужно что бы при выборе  в datePicker например день >=10 и <=21 месяц ==Май(5) в label  передавался текст "Телец". 
Пока что есть это. Но даже этот кусочек кода не работает.

```
 let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: datePicker.calendar,  month: nil, day: nil )
    let day  = dateComponents.day
    let month = dateComponents.month
    if (day >= 10 &&  month == 5)
{
    zodiacLabel.text = "telec"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Что случилось

Похоже, что в приведённом коде не совсем правильно используется `datePicker`. Из него вы берете только параметр `calendar`, хотя по сути надо бы брать дату и уже из нее получать компоненты.

## Как исправить

### Шаг 1. Получение даты

Вот документация `UIDatePicker`, который судя по всему используется: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker. У него есть параметр  `date`. Воспользуемся этим параметром, чтобы получить выбранную пользователем дату:

```
let selectedDate = datePicker.date
```

### Шаг 2. Преобразование в компоненты

Вот документация `Calendar` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar. У него есть метод `dateComponents(_:from:)` для получения компонентов из даты. Воспользуемся этим методом:

```
let components = datePicker.calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: selectedDate)
let day  = dateComponents.day
let month = dateComponents.month
```

### Шаг 3. Отображение результата

Далее у вас всё написано правильно (разве что не хватает проверки на `day < 21` судя по условию)

```
if 10 <= day && day <= 21 && month == 5 {
    zodiacLabel.text = "Телец"
}
```

Comment: Да, вы были правы на счет datePicker. Я исправил и все стало работать .
Большое спасибо за помощ!!

Answer (score 0):

У вас в конструкторе компонентов `month: nil, day: nil`, следовательно и соответствующие переменные тоже будут `nil`. 
Для сравнения попробуйте `let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: datePicker.calendar,  month: 5, day: 15 )`

Comment: Когда я поставил в конструкторе  (day: 1 ), то в независимости от того какой я день выберу оно пишет  в label "telec" . Такое чувство что оно просто игнорирует условие в  конструкции if

Comment: а вы уверены, что строка `zodiacLabel.text = "telec"` внутри `if` при таком условии выполняется? Попробуйте поставить на условии точку останова и посмотрите в отладчике. Если `day` содержит 1, то условие `if (day >= 10 &&  month == 5)` никак не может быть `true`